# How to assign and return multiple values from Django cache?

Tags: python, django, function, caching

Not sure if this is a django issue or just a python issue. I'm trying to get cache working by accepting the values from a function that returns multiple values.

Currently the page is giving me this error on the heavy_view function: "'NoneType' object is not iterable"

Is there anyway to get the "counter, college_user, name_college_list = cache.get(cache_key)" line working? And then the check for if its empty or not. Thanks!

```
 #Views.py

 def filter_results():
     #some code here

     return counter, college_user, name_college_List    


 def heavy_view(request):
     cache_key = 'facebookcache'
     cache_time = 180 # time to live in seconds
     counter, college_user, name_college_list = cache.get(cache_key)
     if not cache.get(cache_key):
         result = filter_results() # some calculations here
         cache.set(cache_key, result, cache_time)
     return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
result = cache.get(cache_key)
if not result:
    result = filter_result()
    cache.set(cache_key, result, cache_time)

counter, college_user, name_college_list = result
```

Comment: Most efficient and effective answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is a Python thing

when you do

```
counter, college_user, name_college_list = cache.get(cache_key)
```

the first time no value will be there -> `None` is returned.
does tis work?

```
result = cache.get(cache_key)
if result is None:
    result = filter_results()
    cache.set(cache_key, result, cache_time)
else:
    counter, college_user, name_college_list = result
return result
```